# Generating numbers in python loop with specific number

Tags: python, loops

I want to add `arg 1` to a range of numbers while generating in python:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1]:
    for i in xrange(0,200000):
        print "%s%05d"%(arg, i)
```

But this is not working...

I want `argv[1]` just be a number!

For example:

```
python script.py 012345
01234500000
01234500001
01234500002
.
.
.
```

Comment: If `argv[1]` will just be number, how you will iterate over it. Because iteration is only possible over a sequence in python. And integer number is not a sequence.

Comment: Your question is unclear: is that first argument supposed to be an offset to the range?

Comment: @Evert Please see my question is updated... `argv[1]` may starts with `0` or not... but the point is sys.argv[1] must be only number

Comment: But do you want to *add* it to `i`, or do you want to *append* to (the string version of) `i`? Your first sentence says "I want to add ...", but your code shows "append". The reason is that if the former, your code can be quite different.

Comment: @Evert ... I want to append I mean/// So how can I get my desired output...I want numbers only..but when I use number started with `0` it won't show me because of int type...if I use str... so if I say `0123dd` as arg 1 it would also generating results for me...and this is not what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its good practice to have a check for your argv length.

**EDIT**

I've modified the solution to only allow numeric arguments but keep pre-leading zeros.

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and str(sys.argv[1]).isdigit():
    for i in xrange(0,200000):
        print "%s%05d"%(str(sys.argv[1]), i)
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and not str(sys.argv[1]).isdigit():
    print ("Given argument must be digit!")
else:
    print ("Wrong number of arguments")
```

Comment: It has a problem... When I say `0123dd` as sys.argv[1] it is working... but I don't want it... @Duncan

Comment: use int(sys.argv[1]) for integers

Comment: No..I want get just numbers

Comment: Is your input a fixed length? if so you can pad it too, print "%05d%05d"%(int(sys.argv[1]), i)

Comment: Please review the updated answer, it should suffice.

Comment: I want if str is in digit pint error..for example: `0123dd` so it prints `Given argument must be digit!` then exit

Comment: The solution has been updated, if it needs further tweaking [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68207/discussion-between-duncan-and-mortezalsc).

Comment: @Samuel that functionality wasn't requested, amongst other cases like irrational numbers and complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try/except block to make sure the argument is both present and a valid integer, then proceed from there...

```
import sys

try:
    base = int(sys.argv[1])
# Handle where argument is not present or not an integer
# Either exit, set a default value or whatever
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    raise SystemExit('must supply an integer value as first argument')

# Do whatever
N = 20
for num in xrange(N):
    print '{0:05}{1:05}'.format(base, num)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As we are accepting `string` as `number` then do `type conversion` from `string` to `int` and handle `exception` if user give wrong input string e.g. 0112eweee
2. If we want output as `String` and do not want to strip `0` from string(beginning) and use `string format` method.
3. If we want output in `int` then use mathematics process to create number. Function `addByMaths()` does maths operation.

Code:

```
import sys
def addByMaths(arg):
    arg *= 100000
    print "=========Maths========"
    for i in xrange(0,10):
        print arg+i

def appendByString(arg):
    print "=========String========"
    tmp = arg+"%05d"
    for i in xrange(0,10):
        print tmp%(i)
try:
    arg_o = sys.argv[1]
    arg_i = int(arg_o)
    #- Add according to maths.
    addByMaths(arg_i)
    #- Append by String method 
    appendByString(arg_o)
except:
    print "Invalid input."
```

Output:

```
python test.py 01
=========Maths========
100000
100001
100002
100003
100004
100005
100006
100007
100008
100009
=========String========
0100000
0100001
0100002
0100003
0100004
0100005
0100006
0100007
0100008
0100009
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do the trick. sys.argv[1] contains the string value "123456", with your first for loop you're iterating over the different parts of the string.

```
def isint(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

arg = sys.argv[1]
if isint(arg):
    for i in xrange(0,200000):
        print "%s%05d"%(arg, i)
```

Comment: Thank you... Good answer but when I set 0123456.. it won't print `0` in result...

Comment: If user string value is `"012345"` and you do not want to strip `0` then do not convert `string` value to `integer` value . just like `arg = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @Vivek Sable ok..but you see I can say `0123dd` and script works... I just want number be accepted

Comment: yes, correct. good to use type conversion. if you are accepting string of digits. but finally code is print string.